# How can i make a box with 940px width fixed inside a scrollable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a fixed box with `980px width` and `500px height` scrolling inside a div with `100% width` and `1500px height`, but it is not working at all.

That's what I did: https://jsfiddle.net/zjuyuhmz/2/embedded/result/

The box is moving when the page scrolls, and I want to make scroll only if the mouse is inside of the div.

Is this possible??

Html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container2">
                <div class="test"></div>
                <div class="test"></div>
                <div class="test"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #a3265e;
    font-family: 'GillSans-SemiBold';
}
.main {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 380px;
}
.container {
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.container2 {
    height: 1500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.test {
  width: 940px;
  height: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -480px;
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: Not sure If I'm understanding your question rightly, but have you tried changing `position: fixed` to `position: absolute`?

Comment: i want make the box follow the scroll @TommyJinks, if i set the position to absolute this will not happen..

Comment: add overflow:scroll to the bigger div

Comment: which div you want to fix inside which other div?

Comment: the test i want to be fix inside the container2 @Sukanya

Comment: nop.. because the test is scrolling when the mouse is in the page, and not when is inside the div =(

Comment: I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SukanyaHalder/vctd0xx9/6/) check this one.

Comment: the test is not fixed in this one @Sukanya

Answer (score 0):

You need to write javascript code, where you can get cursor position and depending on that enable scroll event.

Comment: Yuo don't need javascript for this. See: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

Answer (score 0):

Replace the css for .test for this:

```
.test {
width: 940px;
height: 500px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -480px;
background: black;
}

.test:focus {
position:fixed;
}
```

This means: when the element with id "test" has the focus on, make it's position fixed. If not, make it's position absolute.